# Information from the exception object via java.util.logging

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I want to make logging during my java application development. I want the information from the exception object during exception handling. Which information inquiry from the object is preferred? Using the .getMessage() method, or the .toString() method?

My .getMessage() code snippet:

```
try {
    //my code
} catch( Exception ex ) {
    log.log( Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex );
}
```

My .toString() code snippet:

```
try {
    //my code
} catch( Exception ex ) {
    log.log( Level.SEVERE, ex.toString(), ex );
}
```

Comment: Well, which one has proved more useful to you when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, an exception `toString()` method will put together the name of the exception class and the message of the exception. Therefore, the only difference with `getMessage` is that `toString()` will give you also the class of the exception.

Now, either way, `java.util.logging` will prints the name of the class, its message and the stacktrace anyway because you pass the exception as the third argument of the call to `log`. Therefore, it is useless to provide the result of `getMessage()` or `toString()`. You should instead put a message indicating the context in which the exception happened, and other relevant information.

For example, consider the following:

```
    String identifier = "duck";

    try {
        int result = Integer.parseInt(identifier);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to parse the identifier.", e);
    }
```

Since "duck" is not an integer, this will result in an exception. The program will then print:

```
SEVERE: Failed to parse the identifier.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "duck"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at test.DDD.main(DDD.java:13)
```